# How to include asset files in an Electron Fiddle?

Tags: node.js, path, electron, icons

Because Electron Fiddles seem to be moved to temporary directories before execution, and the icon files seem not to be moved - it seems like there's no way to use an icon file in Electron Fiddle.

Unfortunately I'm not able to browse inside the temporary folder it uses. It uses a path like: `C:\Users\Myself\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-5140Y2pLIyecwgqw\`

Is it accurate to think it's not possible, or is there some workaround?